# Apple pencil unable to click(by touch) when using Kendo UI

Tags: cordova, kendo-ui, telerik, phonegap, apple-pencil

I am Using kendo.all.min.js and kendo.mobile.min.js
when adding data attribute, "view" (data-role = view) in HTML and binding in js file, click events only by apple pencil touch doesn't seem to work. It's working fine with hand.

Any comments would be appreciated.